# How to place a big heading in JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a `JLabel` in which only some part of the text should be big (like a heading) and the other part should be of normal size? When i have used the `setFont()` method i got everything in the same font.

How could i do this?

Comment: [JLabel supports HTML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use HTML for this

```
label.setText("<html><h1>Heading</h1><br/>Some other text here.</html>");
label.setFont(new Font("Myriad Pro",Font.PLAIN,15));
```